# Replicate Elastic Search Primary Shards

Tags: elasticsearch, replication

How to replicate the Elastic Search Primary Shards to additional secondary nodes. During the initial data load the replication was turned off , how do we re-trigger the replication

Answer (score 0):

You are lucky, as you can increase the replica shards dynamically, as the **number of replica** is part of index settings, you just need to update the number by [update index-setting API](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/indices-update-settings.html).

```
PUT /my-index-000001/_settings
{
  "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 2 --> change it according to your replication requirement
  }
}
```

Comment: So if I don't have any replica currently i.e only Primary Shards then can I enable replica of existing Shards by                                                                                                            PUT /my-index-000001/_settings
{
  "index" : {
    "number_of_replicas" : 0 --> change it according to your replication requirement
  }
}

Comment: @Liv_Pool yes you can :)